# Photoshop 2021: Image dragged in changes size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

I've created a large Artboard. My goal is to create a map of game images.

If I open the image in photoshop first, then from this tab, duplicate it as new layer on the artboard, everything is good, and my pixellated image looks sharp.

If I drag the image from explorer into Photoshop, the image changes size, and becomes blurry.

How can I drag the image into photoshop directly not get it to resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

When you create an image, you can also specify its resolution based on pixels per inch. By default, this is 72ppi. If dragging in your image resizes the image, then the original image was not saved as 72ppi.

To fix the issue, open your original image so its a new tab. Then in the bottom left, where it shows you the image resolution, look at how many ppi this image has.

Now, go back to your main Artboard image, go to <kbd>Image</kbd> -> <kbd>Image Size...</kbd> and change the resolution ppi to whatever your image is.

Note that changing the ppi will automatically resize the document itself. Change this back to 100% if you don't want this to happen. Resampling can be turned off if you want, but for this operation, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Once you set the ppi for your document, dragging in any image will scale that image towards this new ppi.

Keep in mind that if you have multiple documents with different ppi's you may want to open each document, and use the duplicate layer to transfer them into your document rather than to drag them in.